# Unpack the series object in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
   userId  movieId  ...  vote_average  vote_count
0       1       31  ...           7.7      5415.0
1       1     1029  ...           6.9      2413.0
2       1     1061  ...           6.5        92.0
3       1     1129  ...           6.1        34.0
4       1     1172  ...           5.7       173.0
```

This is the column from the DataFrame I would like to unpack

```
this is genrecol
0    [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, '...
1    [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, '...
2    [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, ...
3    [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...
4                       [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
Name: genres, dtype: object
```

I would like the result to be:

```
0    ['Animation','Comedy','Romance']
1    ['Adventure','Action','Romance']
2    ['Romance', 'Comedy']
.
.
.
```

It is my understanding that the column 'genrecol' is a Series and an object. I would like some guidance to get the result I desire.

Comment: can u present a complete sample of ur dataframe, without the ```...```.  it can be a subset of rows and columns, but should be complete. makes it easier to work with.  and share what steps u tried

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension in `apply`:

```
import json

df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: [y['name'] for y in json.loads(x)])
```

Or nested list comprehension:

```
df['genres'] = [[y['name'] for y in json.loads(x)] for x in df['genres']]
```

Comment: I did try that method before: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @RoobeshBalaji - Can you test now?

Comment: @RoobeshBalaji - So `df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: [y['name'] for y in json.loads(x)])` not working?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I was able to come up with:

```
#creating a list of all elements in genrecol
list_1= []

for element in genrecol:
    list_1.append(element)

print(list_1)



#removing the unnecessary things from string 
list_1 = list(map(lambda x:x.replace('name','').replace('id','').replace('{','').replace('}','').replace(':','').replace(" '' ",'').replace("''", '').replace(",'","'").replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(' ','').replace("'",''),list_1))

print(list_1)
print(type(list_1))


#removing digits
result = [] 
for s in list_1:
    result.append(''.join([i for i in s if not i.isdigit()]))

print(result)


#putting cleaned string into new array
newres = []
for i in result:
    newres.append(i.split(','))

print(newres)
```